# how to create a textView that changes texts automatically after some seconds

Tags: android, textview

im trying to create a textView that would contain Tips that i typed. And these tips would be stored in a sting Array as show below. how can i make the item in this string array change after a few seconds

```
    </string-array>
<string-array >
    <item> Use low energy compact fluorescent lamps as replacements for traditional incandescent lamps.</item>
   <item >Ensure that thermostats for appliances are effective and set at moderate levels.</item>
    <item >Install low-flow shower heads and faucet aerators to reduce water usage and its associated energy for heating></item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: do you mean change between the items or actually change the item?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problems did you encounter? Nobody here is going to write your code for you. You can use a `Timer`. [Link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
    final String[] tipsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tips); 

    final Handler tipsHanlder = new Handler();
    Runnable tipsRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            int tipPosition = 0;
            //set number of tip(randon/another way)
            tipsTextView.setText(tipsArray[tipPosition]);
            tipsHanlder.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
    tipsHanlder.post(tipsRunnable);
```

You'll need to provide the tip number, based on Randon Generator or another method.

P.S give your String array a name in the XML.